# What does the lever disk adjust?

Tags: motorcycle, kawasaki, handlebars

The clutch as well as the front brake lever has this rotating disk on it. What does it do?
[image: lever 1]
[image: lever 2]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These disks adjust the resting position of the hand levers, to accommodate different-sized hands and rider preference.